# Flexible html mockup with align

Tags: html, css

I have structure like:

```
<style>
#main{
   max-width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
#container{
    margin-right: -50px;
}
.block{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
</style>
<div id="main">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I have wide width it looks like 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I1yM.png
It's ok.

But if I use narrow it sucks
I need that internal bloks is aligned to center like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXMJ.png

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ALR8P/  
But i don't understand your question

Comment: When you use narrow width blocks sticks to the left, but I need that they are aligned to the center like  http://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXMJ.png

Answer (score 1):

Hi what you need here is the property `text-align:center`:

```
#container{
  margin-right: -50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/u5HHc/**

Comment: Yes but the last block will be on center too. it's not like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXMJ.png

Comment: Then you may need some Jquery or Js

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ALR8P/3/

Remove margin from blocks, user text-align justify and add word spacing if you want some fixed space for your blocks on the last row.

```
#container {
  letter-spacing: 10px; //word-spacing: 10px; //to space blocks on last row
  text-align: justify; //to align everything to the borders on the first lines
  padding: 0px 10px; //to separate the blocks from the borders a little
}

.block {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

It looks wrong when width is too small and only one block fits on each row but maybe there you need some media query to make your css responsive to fix that on that special case.

EDIT: letter-spacing works better crossbrowser http://jsfiddle.net/ALR8P/5/, you may want letter-spacing: 30px; since your margin was 30px

Comment: Poor one; All .block element on the second row display wrongly.

Comment: if you set a word-spacing of 10px they look right http://jsfiddle.net/ALR8P/4/ that's the comment i put on that css line